# dropdown select menu from gmail

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to do the dropdown menu from gmail using bootstrap.

[image]

but I have 2 problems:

1- I can't click in the input checkbox to select all

2 - i would like if a select all  the input get selected and if i select none remove the select from the input

so: if I click (all) select the input, if i click (none) remove the select from the input and if i click in the (input box )beside the arrow down select all, understand?

sorry for this might be wrong, i am just trying to make this google gmail button sample, is other way to do this? thank you

html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dJDHd/2157/

Comment: Your `<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">` is in button that's why check box not selected.

Comment: What do you want to get selected? The checkboxes or the list ?

Comment: if I click all select the input, if i click none remove the select from the input and if i click in the input box select all, understand?

Comment: You can not nest input into button, that is invalid HTML.

Comment: sorry for this, i am just trying to make this google gmail button sample, is other way to do this? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I converted the BUTTON into a div, however I kept the classes as "btn btn-default...". This allowed me to play with .mouseenter and .mouseout on the CHECKBOX. Have a look the the [forked jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpardon/otru1zg2/). Seems to do what you needed.

```
$('body').on('mouseenter','input',function() {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', true);
});
$('body').on('mouseout','input',function() {
    $('.btn').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: thanks @cpardon but is not working :(, so: if I click (all) select the input, if i click (none) remove the select from the input and if i click in the (input box )beside the arrow down select all, understand?

Comment: Note: I believe you should only post a question to obtain one answer. Your question should actually be 2 separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#checkAll").click(function () {
    $(".check").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
            <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">None</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me out
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me out
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me out
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me out
   <input type="checkbox" class="check"> Check me out
```

Comment: sorry this did not help me :( and your code is not working

Comment: whats wrong ? it same function like gmail if you check all ckeckboxes are chekced